# attempting to create a string map and insert items results in incomprehensible error spew

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I would like to create a simple map like this:

```
                std::map<const std::string, const std::string> mymap;
                mymap.insert("foo", "bar");
```

when I try this, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/map:60:0,
                 from /home/me/dev/some-project/blocks/mycompany/some-project/main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Arg&&) [with _Arg = const char&; _Key = const std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >; _Compare = std::less<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1722:37:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(_II, _II) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _Key = const std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >; _Compare = std::less<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_map.h:671:11:   required from ‘void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _Key = const std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = const std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = std::less<const std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >]’
/home/me/dev/some-project/blocks/mycompany/some-project/main.cpp:38:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1478:63: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const std::basic_string<char> > >) (const char&)’
  = _M_get_insert_hint_unique_pos(__position, _KeyOfValue()(__v));
                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from /home/me/dev/some-project/blocks/mycompany/some-project/main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:486:12: note: candidates are:
     struct _Select1st
            ^...
```

It goes on and on, but I cannot tell what the problem is from the error output.

I cannot paste the rest of it because stackoverflow says I have too much code and not enough text.

Comment: it should be `.insert({"foo", "bar"})`, note the brackets

Comment: Use `emplace()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `insert()` when you should be using `emplace()` or `operator[]`. 
However, you can't use `const std::string` when using `operator[]`.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
mymap["foo"] = "bar";
```

If you're really bent on using `insert()` and `const std::string`, you have to insert an `std::pair<const std::string, const std::string>`.

```
std::map<const std::string, const std::string> mymap;
std::pair<const std::string,const std::string> p("foo", "bar");
mymap.insert(p);
```

Then there's the C++11 way, using an initializer list:

```
std::map<const std::string, const std::string> mymap;
mymap.insert({ "foo", "bar" });
```

Answer (score 2):

That's simply not how you use `std::map<..>::insert` in C++. You should insert a `std::pair<std::string,std::string>(std::string("a"), std::string("b"))`. See your [arbitrary C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/).

You might get away without using `std::string("a")`, because there's a `std::string` constructor that takes C strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `std::pair` into a map using `insert`.

```
mymap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, const std::string>("a", "b"));
```